# Django admin: Exclude fields in listing but not in editing

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following config:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.CharField('Author', max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
    language = models.CharField('Language', max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
    content = models.TextField('Content', blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active', blank=False, null=False, default=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'blog'
        verbose_name_plural = "Blogs"


class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Blog
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'language', 'is_active')
    search_fields = ('title', 'author', 'language')

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

The **content** field is TextField and huge (up to 200kb).

In the **list_display** option, I haven't added **content** because of the same reason. But, the SQL query on the listing page gets all the fields and then displays selected.

SQL Query (Pagination):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `blog`;
SELECT `blog`.`id`, `blog`.`title`, `blog`.`author`, `blog`.`language`, `blog`.`content`, `blog`.`is_active` FROM `blog` ORDER BY `blog`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 500;
```

SQL Query (Search):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `blog` WHERE (`blog`.`title` LIKE '%search_query%' OR `blog`.`author` LIKE '%search_query%' OR `blog`.`language` LIKE '%search_query%');
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `blog`;
SELECT `blog`.`id`, `blog`.`title`, `blog`.`author`, `blog`.`language`, `blog`.`content`, `blog`.`is_active` FROM `blog` WHERE (`blog`.`title` LIKE '%search_query%' OR `blog`.`author` LIKE '%search_query%' OR `blog`.`language` LIKE '%search_query%') ORDER BY `blog`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The problem is that the query gets slower (sometimes times out) because it is fetching **content**  field every time, even though it is not required in the listing page.

I don't need the **content** field to be selected in the listing page, but it should be editable while adding/editing blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override the default queryset returned back by `ModelAdmin`, [docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).defer('content')
        return qs
```